# Invalid column name 'Schedule_IdSchedule'. No inheritance and there is no such column in DB. One-to-Many

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I use `Entity Framework 6.1.3` Code First to map to an existing database. I've googled many questions about this error, however all errors connected with inheritance, but I have not used inheritance. I've tried to delete my database and recreate all tables, but error is not gone.

I have really simple Database just with two tables - `Schedules` and `Seances`:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Schedules] (
    [IdSchedule]   INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Cinema]       VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [Movie]        VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [DateSchedule] DATETIME     NULL,
    [IdSeance]     INT          NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdSchedule] ASC)
);
```

and:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Seances] (
    [IdSeance]   INT      IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [DateSeance] DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([IdSeance] ASC)
);
```

and Model classes:

```
public class Schedule
{
    [Key]
    public int IdSchedule { get; set; }
    public string Cinema { get; set; }
    public string Movie { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSchedule { get; set; }
    public List<Seance> Seances { get; set; }
}

public class Seance
{
    [Key]
    public int IdSeance { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSeance { get; set; }
}
```

and EFDBContext class:

```
public class EFDbContext : DbContext
{
    public EFDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(null);
    }
    public DbSet<Schedule> Schedules { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Seance> Seances { get; set; }
}
```

However, when I try to execute these rows of code:

```
var e1= EFDbContext.Schedules.ToList();//it works okay
var e2 = EFDbContext.Seances.ToList();// An exception occurs
```

In the second row an exception occurs:

> "Invalid column name 'Schedule_IdSchedule'."}  System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}

The most interesting thing that I do not have column name `Schedule_IdSchedule`. Where does Entity Framework take this column?
How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see unwanted columns in the pattern of "table_fkcolumn" that means EF stuck that in there itself because it couldn't interpret your model. If you want one schedule to many seances, try this:

```
public class Schedule
{
    public Schedule()
    {
        Seances = new List<Seance>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int IdSchedule { get; set; }
    public string Cinema { get; set; }
    public string Movie { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSchedule { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Seance> Seances { get; set; }
}

public class Seance
{
    [Key]
    public int IdSeance { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateSeance { get; set; }
    public int IdSchedule { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IdSchedule")]
    public virtual Schedule Schedule{ get; set; }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a fluent configuration in which case you can remove the annotations and override OnModelCreating:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{            
   modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

   modelBuilder.Entity<Schedule>()
       .HasMany(u => u.Seances)
       .WithRequired()
       .HasForeignKey(h => h.IdSchedule);           
}
```

Comment: what does `{ Seances = new List<Seance>(); }` mean in `Schedule` class? My compilator does not know about this construction.

Comment: Sorry, missing constructor part. Edited.

Comment: thanks, I've tried your code, however, I've got another exception: **"Invalid column name 'IdSchedule'**. Maybe you have another suppositions?

Comment: See http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: Do you have an initializer like DropCreate that changes the database?

Comment: Change your initializer to one that will drop and recreate your database when the model changes while you are in development. Then later on you can turn it off or switch to migrations. http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/28/database-initializer-and-migrations-seed-methods/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108040/discussion-between-stepup-and-steve-greene).

Comment: Try: Database.SetInitializer<EFDbContext>(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<EFDbContext>());

Answer (score 0):

I think you renamed your table from schedule to schedules.
try to refresh your dbcontext.
of it still doesn't work, delete table schedule from your dbcontext schema and readd it. it will work.

Comment: 1. How can I refresh `DBContext`?  please, show code 2. How can I delete table `Schedule` from `DBContext`? please, show code

Comment: open dbcontext schema and right click on the concerned table you will find delete. Than another click right and choose refresh dbcontext to add you table

Comment: I do not have dbcontext schema. I am using Code First approach

Comment: The table name didn't change - it is pluralized by code first.

Answer (score 0):

Your code first model does not mirror your DB schema. I can see that Schedule class contains a List of Seances, so i assume that the relationship between those two classes is one-to-many:

```
Schedule 1-* Seance
```

Instead in your DB schema the Schedules table contains a field that is not mapped in your model (IdSeance), which is also required (NOT NULL constraint). Also this appear to be a foreign key for the table Seances, but no FOREIGN KEY constraint is declared. This DB schema is more similar to this kind of relationship (many-to-one):

```
Schedule *-1 Seance
```

Which is the opposite.

Before continue please figure out the correct relationship between your entities and remember to map exactly every field you need in your class that exists in the DB. Also remember to map those fields as foreign key if they are not following the EF convention for navigation properties. You can do it using [attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583#Relationships) or the [fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).